# SQL no such function YEAR

Tags: sql, date

There are 2 tables
CUSTOMERS(ID, FIRSTNAME, LASTNAME, ADDRESS);
ORDERS (ID, PRODUCT_NAME, PRODUCT_PRICE, DATE_ORDER, ID_CUSTOMER, AMOUNT);
The task is to show all orders (all fields), that have been made before year 2015 and sort the data by ID.
This my code:

```
SELECT * FROM ORDERS
WHERE YEAR(DATE_ORDER) < 2015
ORDER BY ID
```

Error when executed:
no such function YEAR
I tried to do that like this:

```
SELECT * FROM ORDERS
WHERE strfttime('%Y', DATE_ORDER) < 2015
ORDER BY ID
```

and still doesn't work

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would advise you to write the code using date logic:

```
where date_order < date('2015-01-01') -> "I tried this one and it worked" - author of the post
```

Standard SQL uses the function `extract()`:

```
where extract(year from date_order) < 2015
```

However, the exact syntax for both depends on the database you are using.

Answer (score 4):

This smells like SQLite.  Assuming that your dates be in the format `YYYY-MM-DD` you could try:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM ORDERS
WHERE CAST(SUBSTR(DATE_ORDER, 1, 4) AS integer) < 2015
ORDER BY ID;
```